# How to align label and radio button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, twig

When you read this... I probably still haven't solved my issue,

I'm trying to align the label and radiobutton, I have tried alot of "Solutions", but nothing works. I have no css on the radio buttons that i created myself.

Output: http://prntscr.com/5am898

My Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="btnRadio">
           <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2015lbl">
               <input name="galTab" id="gal2015" value="2015" type="radio">2015
           </label>
           <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2014lbl">
               <input name="galTab" id="gal2014" value="2014" type="radio">2014
           </label>
           <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2013lbl">
               <input name="galTab" id="gal2013" value="2013" type="radio">2013
           </label>
           <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2012lbl">
               <input name="galTab" id="gal2012" value="2012" type="radio">2012
           </label>
           <label class="radio-inline" for="galOtherlbl">
               <input name="galTab" id="galOther" value="Anders" type="radio">And
           </label>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect Element CSS: Label:http://prntscr.com/5am7uz Input:http://prntscr.com/5am7zc

Comment: You should make a div that will contain both label and radio button. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/fm976xcj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the input outside the label.

```
<label class="radio-inline" for="galOtherlbl">
    And
</label>
<input name="galTab" id="galOther" value="Anders" type="radio">
```

Comment: @Anona: i answered so early

Answer (score 1):

put the label in label tag like

```
<label class="radio inline control-label">Some label</label>
```

try

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dch6eac1/1/)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="btnRadio">

               <input name="galTab" id="gal2015" value="2015" type="radio">
               <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2015lbl">2015</label>

               <input name="galTab" id="gal2014" value="2014" type="radio"> 
               <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2014lbl">2014</label>

               <input name="galTab" id="gal2013" value="2013" type="radio">
               <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2013lbl">2013</label>

               <input name="galTab" id="gal2012" value="2012" type="radio" />
               <label class="radio-inline" for="gal2012lbl">2012</label>

               <input name="galTab" id="galOther" value="Anders" type="radio"/>
               <label class="radio-inline" for="galOtherlbl">And</label>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```